# I am using the pig-0.11.1 , I want to group the records based on the skill set of th e employee

Tags: apache-pig

given my input data in (employee name, employee id , skill ) format

```
Employee_name1 , 1001, Sql
Employee_name1 , 1001, Java
Employee_name2 , 1002, Sql
Employee_name2 , 1002, Php
Employee_name3 , 1003, Sql
Employee_name3 , 1003, Php
Employee_name3 , 1003, Linux
```

want to group the tuples on the third field and merge the bags with a set semantic to get the following tuples as output

```
Employee_name1, 1001, Sql;java
Employee_name2, 1002, Sql;Php
Employee_name3, 1003, Sql;php,linux
```

Comment: How are you merging the bags? Into a string I am guessing?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.